# Laravel SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i want to create a foreign key but nothing work and i don't understand why[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQxhk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WScD.png)

Comment: Those error messages are horrible to read. Make the effort you're expecting from others in order to help you, and copy your code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info about table type, for now based on info that you type I can suggest you check are you using InnoDB tables? does FOREIGN KEY in table one corresponding to PK in table 2? are they have same types and length?

Answer (score 0):

articles table

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArticlesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title' , 255);
            $table->text('content');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
    }
}
```

category table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoryTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('category');
    }
}
```